# Moving CTA Button

Tags: html, css

I have a Call to Action button on my page that I am trying to move slightly to the right in order to line up better with the text/images above it on the page.  Everything I try either moves it behind other elements or does nothing at all.  Any tips/tricks/solutions would be great.  CSS is listed below.  Thanks.

```
        .cta-button {
    margin: 10px auto;
    clear: both;
    float: none !important;
    padding-left:30px;
    height: auto !important;
}
            .cta-on-phone-alignment { text-align: center !important; clear: both     !important; height: 70px; 0 0 0; vertical-align: baseline !important; }
             img.hero {
    clear: inherit !important;
    margin: 0 auto !important;
    text-align: center !important;
    float: none !important;
}
```

HTML where the button is located.  If there needs to be more, please let me know.  I'm kinda new to Web design, so much of this is still confusing to me.

```
<div class="row cta-on-phone-alignment">
                            <!-- Button links to bottom of page -->
                            <a href="#bottom" class="cta-button" style="text-align:center !important;">Contact Us</a> <!-- Call To Action Button -->
                        </div>
```

Comment: Please post your HTML. A jsFiddle.net example would be helpful too.

Comment: It will be all the `!important` declarations affecting it. You will either need to remove them or add inline CSS. An example or more code, would help.

Comment: I edited in some of the HTML...if I need to post more, please let me know what is needed.  Thank you.

Comment: After I remove the !important declarations, where would I need to add the right/left properties without messing with any of the other elements on the page.  As I said, I'm still new to this whole programming thing and some of the basics are still confusing to me.

Comment: Issue was resolved by using a combination of a few of the answers and comments listed...removed the !important declarations, used relative positions in the HTML and the CSS, added a z-index, and adjusted the move properties in the HTML.  Multiple eyes were needed and that is what I got.  Thanks a lot, programmers.  You were a great help once again.

Answer (score 0):

To ensure the button is at the front of the stack, you need to use z-index AND positioning.

try

```
.cta-button {
  margin: 10px auto;
  clear: both;
  float: none !important;
  padding-left:30px;
  height: auto !important;

  position: relative;
  z-index: 1000;
}
```

It would help a lot if you could post your HTML too though!

Comment: I posted the code for the div that controls the cta button.  Any other parts of the HTML or CSS that I need to include?